# ActionBarSherlock R. is not generating

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

Today I had a Problem in another Project and the solution was to hit `Project -> Clean`, but since then  the R. in the ActionBarSherlock-library won't generate. I couldn't solve this problem so I restarted eclipse and downloaded and imported the library again. But the error is still there. The Problem is that there is no red flag in my res folder. If I open the Error-Log I can see a bunch of warnings and errors, but this one is being repeated very much:

```
abs__action_menu_layout.xml: Failed to convert ?attr/actionBarDivider into a drawable
abs__action_menu_item_layout.xml: Couldn't find theme resource attr/actionButtonStyle for the current theme
```

I have the newest version of actionbarsherlock, so I doubt the resource is actually missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have often had this problem where the R.java file will not generate. It occurs when there is a problem with one/many of your resources (Images/Sounds/Layouts etc).

It appears that you have errors in both the XML files mentioned. It looks like `actionBarDivider` and `actionButtonStyle` are not missing/not generated. I would look at the definitions for both of those and see if there are any issues.

Comment: but eclipse doesn't show an error in abs__action_menu_layout.xml or abs__action_menu_item_layout.xml and i haven't found one. I haven't touched the library before and now it is brand new...due to the popularity of actionbarsherlock I doubt that ther is an error in these XML-Files.

Comment: Have you cleaned both your project and actionbarsherlock. Failing that you could try removing both projects and re-adding. Also, try creating a fresh new workspace and adding your projects. Eclipse can act very strange sometimes.

Comment: Yeah I've already readded both and still no R. I think I'll do that if nobody comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the libs folder and then click on the library project Android Tools->Add Support Library. After that make Project->Clean...

If this doesn't help, try to download the fresh version of abs from [officail web-site](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and re-add it to your project.

Comment: Didn't work. I have already downloaded and imported the library again...thats why it's so strange :)